# What is value of $f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + f(5) + f(6)$?

Tags: functions

A  function  $f(x)$  is  defined  so that
$$ f(x)  =  f(x - 2) - x(x  +  2) $$
for  all  the  integer  values  of  $x$  and  $f(1)  +  f(4)  =  0$.  What  is  the  value  of

$$f(1)  + 
f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + f(5) + f(6)?$$

- 0
- 89
- -89
- None of these

This is a practice question from [here](http://alpingi.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Amazon-placement-paper-and-solution-pdf-download-1.pdf), not any test/HW question.

Comment: It seemstha value can be arbitrary (though it willequal $2f(6)$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  I don't find it so and got one of the choices.

Comment: Can you use the recursion relations to get F(2) in terms of F(1) and/or F(4)?  What eventually happens when you do this for all terms and add the results?

Comment: @RossMillikan D'oh, I read $f(x+2)$ where it said $x(x+2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define $f(1)=k$.  You are then given $f(4)=-k$.  Use the recursion to find the other four values in terms of $k$.  When you add them up, the $k$s disappear.

Comment: Got it.I was doing almost this way and hoping things will cancel out but one thing missed was supposing f(1)=k and equations became messy.Thank you for the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + f(5) + f(6)$

As $f(1) + f(4) = 0$, therefore $S = f(2) + f(3) + f(5) + f(6)$  : (1)

$f(2) = f(0) - 8$

$f(3) = f(1) - 15$

$f(4) = f(2) - 24 = f(0) - 32$

$f(5) = f(3) - 35 = f(1) - 50$

$f(6) = f(4) - 48 = f(0) - 80$

Put the above values in equation (1), we get

$S = f(0) - 8 + f(1) - 15 + f(1) - 50 + f(0) - 80$

$S = 2(f(0) + f(1)) - 153$ : (2)

As we already know $f(1) + f(4) = 0 \Rightarrow f(1) + f(0) - 32 = 0 \Rightarrow f(1) + f(0) = 32$

Putting this value in equation (2), we get $S = 2(32) - 153 = -89$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answer.